# WHERE searching in table state before transaction

Tags: mysql

I'm searching for a way to achieve a bunch of UPDATE operations with the WHERE clause searching in the state where table was before the first UPDATE.
I think I can use some TRANSACTION options but I don't understand well the documentation.

An example:
I've got this request running in a foreach loop:

```
UPDATE sometable SET someField = '{$newId}' WHERE someField = '{$oldId}';
```

But sometimes the $oldId is equal to a previous $newId value so update will change to much rows.

EDIT: Some precisions:

Here is a concrete example of what I mean:

```
// Let s say old Ids are the keys and new Ids are the values
$arrayIds = array(1 => 2, 2 => 4, 3 => 2)
foreach ($arrayIds as $oldId => $newId) {
    $req = "UPDATE clients SET contact_id = '$newId' WHERE contact_id = '$oldId';
    $db->query($req); // DB is a database manager object, no matter how it works, this line query the request to server.
}
```

In this example, the first iteration will change every contact_id 1 to 2, in the second iteration contact_id 2 to 4 etc. But when comes the second UPDATE, all rows modified by first iteration will also be changed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not get what you are after. Pls provide a specific example where you would have to use some kind of an old value multiple times.

Comment: Look this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html if your update need to be triggered after one specific action. With some Mysql trigger, you can do : after table1 is update -> update table2 where old.id_table1= id_table2 for example (you have 2 new keyword in your mysql syntax, old.value the value BEFORE the update and new.value the value AFTER the update)

Comment: No, it won't. You got to the wrong conclusion. If `$oldId` is equal to `$previousId` then MySQL won't write a thing. Your comment about transactions is odd, it implies that you don't know what it really is. The gist of the problem is that you *think* you're going to optimize something - you won't. It's already taken care of for you.

Comment: I think you didn't understood what I mean, I updated my post with a concrete example